# Aggregate from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, inner-join, sql-server-2014

I have two tables

Table 'Sales Line' (SL)

```
    Date      "Entry No"    Item    Qty
                (PK)
    01/01/2018     1        ABC     1
    01/02/2018     2        ABC     2
    03/02/2018     3        DEF     1
    04/06/2018     4        DEF     3
    01/01/2019     5        DEF     1
    06/06/2019     6        ABC     2
```

Table 'Cost Breakdown' (CB)

```
    "SL Entry No"   Cost    
        (FK)    
          1         10      
          1         15      
          2          5      
          3         25      
          4         10      
          4         10      
          5          5      
          6          5      
          6         10
```

Expected result:

```
    Item    Tot_Qty Tot_Cost    
    ABC        3     30 
    DEF        4     45
```

Note that I'm only interested on transaction in 2018 only.

How do I aggregate Tot_Qty and Tot_Cost ? Thank you

With [query suggested by @GMB](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/809fe/5/0), the result is :

```
Item    Tot_Qty Tot_Cost    
ABC        4     30 
DEF        7     45
```

so, line from SL will be repeated as many as correponding number of lines in CB.

Answer (score 0):

You can join both tables, filter on the date, and aggregate by item:

```
select sl.item, sum(sl.qty) tot_qty, sum(sl.qty * cb.cost) tot_cost
from sales_line sl
inner join cost_breakdown cb on cb.sl_entry_no = sl.entry_no
where sl.date >= '20180101' and sl.date < '20190101'
group by sl.item
```

Comment: thanks for the response...I've updated the original post with the result of your suggested query.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear....I've tried query suggested by GMB but the result still incorrect. Any further thought ?